# How to put a large text file in to Array?

Tags: java, large-files

I have a large text file. I want to put every character in the text file, in to Character array. I use this code to put it.

```
List<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_path));
String check_line=bf.readLine();
while(check_line!=null){
    set.add(check_line);
    check_line=bf.readLine();
}

ArrayList<Character> charr = new ArrayList<Character>();

for(int j=0;j<set.size();++j){
        String str=set.get(j);
        for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x ++){
        charr.add(str.charAt(x));
        }}

return charr;
```

But it takes long time.Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't think of a good reason for having a `Character[]` of a file's contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each line

```
char[] x = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: How faster will this be?

Comment: A lot, but it's not a `Character[]`, it's a `char[]`, so you can't compare them in any sensible way.

Comment: You might consider adding your brief comments here to the answer to give a little more background about *why* this is a good idea rather than just "try this out."

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Path file = Paths.get("path", "to", "file");
    final Character[] characters = toCharacters(file);
}

public static Character[] toCharacters(final Path file) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)) {
        return lines.flatMapToInt(String::chars).
                mapToObj(x -> (char) x).
                toArray(Character[]::new);
    }
}
```

More efficient coding wise, and fewer intermediate collections created. Not sure it will be much faster however as this involves file IO which is **very slow**.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the line into one string and then convert them to an char array.

```
      public char[]  extractCharArray(String fileName) {
       char[] charArray = null;
       try(BufferedReader bf  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
         StringBuilder completeFileString = new StringBuilder();    
         String check_line=bf.readLine();
           while(check_line!=null){
            completeFileString = completeFileString.append(check_line);
           check_line=bf.readLine();
           }

         charArray = completeFileString.toString().toCharArray();

       } catch(IOException ex) {
         //Handle the exception
       }
     return charArray;
     }
```

Comment: String concatenation in a loop, you must be joking.

Comment: @ Boris : What seems to be the problem with it ?

Comment: Immutable `Strings`, that's what

Comment: [Here is a good article](http://kaioa.com/node/59) on why you shouldn't ever do this. There's also [a good one from Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: okie.Have updated the answer using StrinrBuffer to avoid performance issues

Comment: `StringBuffer` is synchronized, so it slower than `StringBuilder`. No reason to use `StringBuffer`. You also don't close your `Reader` when you are done with it - this is a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for citing out the problem. Have update the answer..:)

Comment: This is still not correct. You should close resources either in a `finally` or, ideally, using a `try-with-resources` construct. If your code throws an exception from the loop then your `Reader` will not be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a list of Strings as a temp variable and don't directly store to your Character List?

```
    ArrayList<Character> charr = new ArrayList<Character>();
    String check_line=bf.readLine();
    while(check_line!=null){
        for(char c : check_line.toCharArray())
            charr.add(c);
        check_line=bf.readLine();
    }

    return charr;
```